# How do I get the amount of child that has the same value?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I get the amount of child (Ex. "1234" & "fdsasda") that has the same value for the category.

Lets say I want to know how many items are in category C, how will I go on about that with a value event listener.

```
 // removed unimportant things
  "1234" : {
    "category" : "C",
  },
  "fdsasda" : {
    "category" : "B",
  },
```

Comment: Hey @Kristofer, do vote the answer up, if it helped you, I'd appreciate that. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, first you have to make sure that there are no parent nodes between the root node and these child nodes that you have shown in your structure.

Then what you can do is, use `orderByChild()` to order your database with the child `category` and use `equalTo()` to compare it to your desired value and count the occurrences.

What I am saying, looks something like this in code:

```java
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

Query query = rootRef.orderByChild("category").equalTo("C");

query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                long count = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                Log.d("TAG", count + "");

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            }


        });
```